# How to convert a new-line delimited JSON file with nested json in each row to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to convert new-line delimited JSON file with nested json in each row to a pandas dataframe. Hard to find anything online.

Comment: Hard to understand what you need without seeing what you have and what you want. Have an example input and output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  please refer to the following guidelines when posting questions  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   , https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example